# Not able to parse DateTime in CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am not able to set up proper DateTime formatting for the given csv format file. I tried different approaches but this one seems to me to be the closest to the truth. How can I set up this to make it work?

```
public class Parser
{
    public static List<Order> ParseCsv()
    {
        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            Delimiter = ";",
            HasHeaderRecord = true,
            TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim,
            MissingFieldFound = null
        };
        using (var reader = new StringReader("'Purchase Date'\r\n'2023-02-14T12:03:40Z'"))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
        {
            csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<PurchaseMap>();
            return csv.GetRecords<Order>().ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class PurchaseMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public PurchaseMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.PurchaseDate).Name("'Purchase Date'").TypeConverterOption.Format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

The error which I got:

> CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException: 'The conversion
> cannot be performed.
> Text: ''2023-02-14T12:03:40Z''
> MemberName: Purchase Date
> MemberType: System.DateTime
> TypeConverter: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.DateTimeConverter'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Jaryn's answer.  You can still use `TypeConverterOption.Format`. Having  the specific format string is the key.

```cs
public class PurchaseMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public PurchaseMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.PurchaseDate).Name("'Purchase Date'").TypeConverterOption.Format("\\'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ\\'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV string is not a usual one, i.e. the values are enclosed by single quote.

Not familiar with that library, I've tried setting `Escape = '\''` in `CsvConfiguration` but it does not work.

By eliminating single quote and change this line your code works:

```
Map(m => m.PurchasDate).Name("Purchas Date").TypeConverterOption.DateTimeStyles(DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
Map(m => m.PurchaseDate).Convert(s => 
DateTime.ParseExact(s.Row.Parser.Record[0], "\\'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ\\'", null));
```

Convert gives the possibility to do the parsing. Records[0] says which parsing 'column' it tries to tackle.